# How to log into a 2FA protected YouTube account in Gear VR?

Tags: youtube, authorization, samsung-gear-vr

While using Gear VR, I tried to access my YouTube account from both Oculus Browser and Samsung Internet.
Since my account is protected by 2-factor authorization, the app tells me to click the "yes" button that should appear on my registered phone.
However, when the Oculus app is running, this notification is not displayed. I tried to remove my phone from the gear, but no notification neither.

What is the easiest way to log into my 2FA-protected YouTube account from Gear VR?

Comment: disable 2FA, then login to VR, then enable again is the most logical step, no?

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me: generate recovery codes from my Google account and use those to log in.